# Pointing to subfolder via .htaccess doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, directory-tree

I'm working on a WP based site.
I have the site of the client on my space (www.mydomainname.com/~subfolder/sub-subfolder).
Now the original domain of the client is pointing to my space (www.clientdomain.com goes directly on the www.domainname.com/~subfolder/) without changing url name. 
But, whent it happens, the server answer giving a directory tree. I would need the site to point directly to sub-subfolder (not to ~subfolder) without giving the directory tree.

I have used this .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymlinks  

RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond &#37;{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomainname\.cc [NC]

RewriteRule .? http://www.mydomainname.cc/~subfolder/ [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

How can I do it? I'm sure I'm doing the same error but I can't find it...
Please help me I'm going crazy!!! :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteRule %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/~subfolder/sub-subfolder%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteRule %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/~subfolder/sub-subfolder%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ /~subfolder/sub-subfolder%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: Thank you @Jon Lin for your answer.
Unfortunately nothing's happened. I have always access to the tree but the folder I need is disappeared.
Any suggestion ?

Comment: @FoxMulder I guess I have no idea what you are asking, what's this "tree" that you have access to?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm not explaining it in the right way.
It's the index of the webspace with 
Apache Server at www.interactiva.cc Port 80 at the bottom and the directories inside.

Comment: @FoxMulder At the bottom of what?

Comment: Dear Jon Lin, the page is like this:

http://www.webhostinghub.com/support/website/website-troubleshooting/why-does-my-site-say-index-of-and-list-my-files

Comment: Now the page is working, however the administrator page is blank. 
I received the error: 

Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.

Comment: @FoxMulder Sounds like your administrator page is from a different domain, in your administrator page there's probably a `Header` config option somewhere (maybe in an htaccess file) that says something like `Header append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN` which makes it so you can't display it in an iframe hosted by another domain. You need to remove this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in an htaccess in ~subfolder/ :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^sub-subfolder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sub-subfolder/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Now the page is working, however the administrator page is blank. I received the error: Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.

Comment: never seen an error like that, can't help you with that sorry :/